# How to upgrade (migrate) a flatpak environment

Tags: linux, gnome, updates, software-update, flatpak

On updating my *Flatpak* with `flatpak update`, I get following message:

```
Info: org.gnome.Platform//3.36 is end-of-life, with reason:
   The GNOME 3.36 runtime is no longer supported as of February 13, 2021. Please ask your application developer to migrate to a supported platform.
Applications using this runtime:
   org.gimp.GIMP
```

I have tried `flatpak repair` to no avail.

Do you know how I can correct this problem? Should I really contact the developers of GNOME 3.36?
Thanks.

By the way my OS is Linux Ubuntu 16.04. LTS (in case it matters)

Answer (score 0):

(based on [this contribution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/641030/warning-on-updating-flatpak-runtime-is-not-longer-supported/641032#641032))

This problem is already commented at the [org.gimp.GIMP thread](https://github.com/flathub/org.gimp.GIMP/issues/84). So the developers of GIMP already know about — we hope they are working on it. ;)

As suggested at the thread, we can provisionally use following workaround to execute GIMP.

```
flatpak run --runtime-version=40 org.gimp.GIMP
```